# Howto getting started with User Mode Linux using rootstrap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-mode-linux

I have *Ubuntu 10.10* installed and would like to create some instances of **User Mode Linux** (UML) using **bootstrap**, but all information I can find seems out-dated, and my simple attempts fails.

Any one that knows this?

I have the following packages installed:

1. uml-utilities
2. user-mode-linux
3. dhcp3-client
4. dhcp3-server

*I would like to get one UML instance up with the ability to connect to internet and install further debian packages with apt-get.*

*How should I configure* **rootstrap.conf**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working in the same area and here are my steps so far:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/33958/how-to-correctly-start-a-ubuntu-user-mode-linux-from-the-command-line